# Determining the boundedness of a sequence related to cunningham chains

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, upper-lower-bounds

(Question was suggested and studied by a friend)
Consider the following sequence:
$$
a_n = \text{least prime divisor of } (2a_{n - 1} + 1)
$$
For example, if $a_1 = 5$, we have $a_2 = 11, a_3 = 23, a_4 = 47, a_5 = 5$ and on.
The question is, for every initial value of $a_1$, is the sequence $a_n$ bounded?

Here are some observations made during the attempts at a solution:

1. If the sequence decreases at a point, then it decreases at least at the order of $x^{1/2}$; this is attained at the case $x = p^2$ for some prime $p$.
2. Considering $a, 2a + 1, 4a + 3, \dots $ modulo $p$ for prime $p$ (this is periodic with period $ p - 1$), for some initial values of $p$, the sequence attains $0$ modulo $p$. For the class of primes $p$ where $2$ has multiplicative order $p - 1$ (modulo $p$), it is possible to prove that $x$ must be $p - 1$ modulo $p$, however as it is not known even whether this class is infinite or not, this is impossible to use.
3. If the length of the increasing part (a *Cunningham chain*) is asympotically $O(\log p)$ with initial value $p$, then the number increases polynomially, and with some refining of bounds, it is possible that the descending part of the sequence may dominate the ascending part, and force the sequence into a cycle. However, the only result known is that the length is $O(p)$. A preprint paper has a conditional result: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.07650.pdf.
4. Intuition suggests, and numerical experiments further shows that the least prime divisor operation is much more rapidly decreasing than $x^{1/2}$; however because of the number-theoretical nature of the function, it is very difficult to gain any good estimates. A study on factors of numbers of the form $2p + 1$ with $p$ prime may be fruitful.

Comment: This is one of those conjectures (the sequence is always bounded , no matter what $a_1$ is) one feels that it "must be true" , but there is probably no hope for a proof.

Comment: I don't like how such conjectures are abundant in number theory, but they exist anyway...

Comment: One useful thing to note is that for any prime $p \not\equiv 9 \pmod{10}$, there can be no more than three growth steps before you get dropped down to $5$. In mod $10$, $1 \to 3 \to 7 \to 5$, but $9 \to 9$. So you can skip any prime not ending in $9$. Additionally, any prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ will jump to a multiple of $3$; so we need only examine primes of the form $3k-1$, which combined with the requirement to end in $9$ means primes of the form $30k-1$.

Comment: Using modular arithmetic should be useful; however using only modulo cannot work because for any $k$, $p = ak - 1$ implies that $2p + 1 = 2ak - 1$, and also that $k - 1$ and $k$ are relatively prime.
Also, Dirichlet's theorem says that there are infinitely many primes of the form $ak - 1$.

Comment: Yes, exactly! $2p+1=60k-1$, and the next term is $120k-1$, and so forth. Other than $2$ and $5$, all (positive) Cunningham chains with more than $3$ primes in a row must begin with a prime $p_0=30k-1$ for some $k$. The smallest with length $6$ starts at $p_0=89$; the smallest of length $7$ starts at $p_0=1122659$.

Comment: As you pointed out, via Legendre we know there are infinitely many primes in $\{30k-1 \mid k \in \mathbb{N}\}$. But I'm pretty certain that Legendre's theorem does *not* imply there are infinite *sequences* of primes, meaning Cunningham chains will always be bounded, though arbitrarily long ones can be found. The bounds on the *length* of the chains are where the interest lies.